Raspberry Pi Pico CMakeLists.txt add library from GitHub
I'm adding WolfSSL to a pico project as a library in the lib directory and building as a static library. What's the best way to import the WolfSSL source? Is it just a case of cloning or downloading a WolfSSL release from GitHub into a directory? e.g. a project I have seen has this structure:
CMakeLists.txt
...
lib/wolfssl @ 12e2854/

but I'm not sure what 12e2854 refers to in the directory name.

I've made it one question now thanks

Of course you add the include_directories (../../liba ../../libb) etc. and then for sources you target_sources (${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME}.c ../../liba/somesourc.c) and so on to collect all your sources. See target_sources I used to do all coding in any old editor with an xterm to compile in (I still use the xterm), but VSCode with the C/C++ and Cmake plugins make life really nice. I'm one who never thought I'd use an IDE. But as your projects grow, it is the best I've found. vscodium for privacy.

Use FetchContent to fetch WolfSSL and make it available in your project.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)

project(myProject VERSION 1.0.0)

# Allow us to use FetchContent
include(FetchContent)

# Fetch the repository from GitHub
FetchContent_Declare(WolfSSL
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl
    GIT_TAG v5.7.0-stable
)

# Make the repository available to us
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(WolfSSL)

# Link to library statically
target_link_libraries(myProject STATIC WolfSSL)

In addition you probably want to use target_include_directories to give scope to certain WolfSSL folders.
You can decide which tag you wish to fetch, I choose the latest stable that I could find in the repository.
